# appending two variables in os.path.isdir

Tags: python

I am trying to append two variables BUILD_ROOT_DIR and W_ROOT and check if this directory exists ,if not raise a flag...running into following syntax error while appending..what is wrong here?

```
if(os.path.isdir(BUILD_ROOT_DIR + W_ROOT))
    raise

    if(os.path.isdir(BUILD_ROOT_DIR + W_ROOT))
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It is generally recommended, also, to use `os.path.join` rather than string concatenation for joining paths. In particular, it handles the common and reasonable case where the first path doesn't end in a slash, and it also works across platforms.

Answer (score 3):

You need a colon to end the `if` statement (the parentheses are not required):

```
if os.path.isdir(BUILD_ROOT_DIR + W_ROOT):
    raise
```